# Why is Ninject Bind with Interception returning an interface proxy?

Tags: c#, ninject, fluorinefx, ninject-interception

I'm trying to understand how `Ninject.Extensions.Interception` 3.0.0.8 is building dynamic proxies for my classes. I've found that when I decorate my concrete classes with an attribute that inherits from `InterceptAttribute` or when I directly Intercept at binding time with `Intercept()` method then Ninject returns a Dynamic Proxy of the decorated class instead of the normal type.

I have a `IPolicySearchPresenter` interface which I'm binding to `FlexPolicySearchPresenter` concrete type adding an Exception logger interceptor:

```
Bind<IExceptionInterceptor>().To<ExceptionInterceptor>();
Bind<IPolicySearchPresenter>().To<FlexPolicySearchPresenter>().Intercept().With<IExceptionInterceptor>();
```

The problem is that when I inspect the returning type for that binding:

```
var proxy = Kernel.Get<IPolicySearchPresenter>();
```

I get an instance of `Castle.Proxies.IPolicySearchPresenterProxy` instead of `FlexPolicySearchPresenterProxy`

This is giving me problems with my FluorineFx remoting app. However, if I create my Castle Proxy manually:

```
ProxyGenerator generator = new ProxyGenerator();
    //My presenter type
    Type type = typeof(FlexPolicySearchPresenter);
    //My presenter interface
    var interfaceType = type.GetInterfaces().Single();
    //Get my Interceptor from container. Notice that i had to 
    //change my Interceptor to implement IInterceptor from Castle libs,
    // instead of Ninject IInterceptor
    var excepInt = Kernel.Get<ExceptionInterceptor>();
    //Manually get all my instances required by my presenter type Constructor
    //ideally passed through Constructor Injection
    var presenterSearchService = Kernel.Get<IPolicySearchService>();
    var userAuthService = Kernel.Get<IUserAuthorizationService>();
    //Create proxy, passing interceptor(s) and constructor arguments
    var proxy = generator.CreateClassProxy(type, new object[] { presenterSearchService, userAuthService },
            new IInterceptor[]
        {
            excepInt
        });
    //Ninject.Extensions.Interception.DynamicProxyModule
    // I'm using directive ToConstant(..), and not To(..)
    //Bind my interface to the new proxy
    Bind(interfaceType).ToConstant(proxy).InThreadScope();

var proxy = Kernel.Get<IPolicySearchPresenter>();
```

The returning types come back as `Castle.Proxies.FlexPolicySearchPresenterProxy` which work perfectly with my remoting implementation.

The question is, how can I get Ninject.Interception return me instances of `FlexPolicySearchPresenterProxy` instead of `IPolicySearchPresenterProxy`. 
Notice that by doing the manual Castle way I am binding in a different way:

```
        Bind(interfaceType).ToConstant(proxy).InThreadScope();
```

Instead of the ninject way:

```
Bind<IPolicySearchPresenter>().To<FlexPolicySearchPresenter>().Intercept().With<IExceptionInterceptor>();
```

Do I need to change the way I'm doing the Binding in Ninject to get the right type?

Comment: Have you tried creating a binding from IPolicy.. to FlexPolicy *and* then binding FlexPolicy .ToSelf().Intercept().With... ?
(Sidenote: ninject instanciaties interceptors once per type and not once per proxied instance).

Comment: No, I haven't tried that. I'll give it a try this morning. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I did this: `Bind<IPolicySearchPresenter>().To<FlexPolicySearchPresenter>();`
`Bind<FlexPolicySearchPresenter>().ToSelf().Intercept().With<IExceptionInterceptor>();`
`var proxy = Kernel.Get<IPolicySearchPresenter>();` But proxy is comming back as `FlexPolicySearchPresenter` type instead of `FlexPolicySearchPresenterProxy` and interception didn't kick in :(

Comment: Strange. Are there any virtual methods @ FlexPolicySearchPresenter? btw., here is the ninject extension code for dynamic proxy instanciation: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.interception/blob/master/src/Ninject.Extensions.Interception.DynamicProxy/DynamicProxyProxyFactory.cs (note the if(targetType.IsInterface))

Comment: Yes I have a virtual method in my presenter where I'm throwing an exception so my Interceptor manages it. I downloaded Ninject.Extensions.Interception source code for the release I'm using from NuGet but can't get to attach a debugger to it, that would make things much clearer...

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit what would be my target type in my case? I'm a little confused: `Type targetType = context.Request.Service;

            if (targetType.IsInterface)`

Comment: Request.Service is what you want to resolve. So if you have a ctor argument IFoo it's IFoo. If the ctor argument is Foo, then it's Foo. In your case it is IPolicySearchPresenter.

Comment: Regarding debugger: Putting the source @ the following path C:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.extensions.XYZ might be a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: added property injection to Foo.

I've got a working solution for you, but to be honest, i'm not 100% happy about it. Anyway, this works:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<IFoo>().ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<Foo>());

        kernel.Bind<Foo>().ToSelf().Intercept().With<SomeInterceptor>();

        var foo = kernel.Get<IFoo>();

        foo.DoSomething();

        Console.WriteLine(foo.GetType());

        Console.Read();
    }
}

public interface IFoo
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    [Inject]
    public Bar Dependency { get; set; }

    public virtual void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("doing something with {0}", this.Dependency);
    }
}

public class SomeInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public SomeInterceptor()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("interceptor created");
    }

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("before");
        invocation.Proceed();
        Console.WriteLine("after");
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Bar (injected dependency)";
    }
}
```

The resulting output is:

```
interceptor created
before
doing something with Bar (injected dependency)
after
```

And the type is:

```
Castle.Proxies.FooProxy
```

It seems that .Bind().To() *and* .Bind().ToSelf().Intercept... do not have the same result. I don't know why (yet) - but maybe i'm going to investigate it.

**Update on constructor arguments:**
Ninject by itself only supports "inheritance based class proxy" - where the class needs a default / empty ctor and "interface proxy without target" - which is what you don't want.

Therefore, would it be acceptable for you to use property injection "just this once"?
Otherwise you will need to create your own interception ninject-magic and use "class proxy with target" (see http://docs.castleproject.org/Tools.Kinds-of-proxy-objects.ashx)
**Remark**: Even though "class proxy with target" supports constructor arguments you need to know which they are beforehand (so no easy DI support).
(I did not find a hook for resolving constructor arguments after dynamic proxy chooses/creates the constructor for the proxy.)

Comment: I'll try it as soon as my Visual Studio comes back to life. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Didn't work for me. I get this error: "Could not find a parameterless constructor." My FlexPolicySearchPresenter is a little more complex, has constructor injection: `public FlexPolicySearchPresenter(IPolicySearchService policySearchServiceService,
                                         IUserAuthorizationService iUserAuthorizationService)
            : base(iUserAuthorizationService)
        {
            _policySearchService = policySearchServiceService;
        }`

Comment: Yes it comes from Castle.DynamicProxy:    at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxyInstance(Type proxyType, List`1 proxyArguments, Type classToProxy, Object[] constructorArguments)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy(Type classToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options, Object[] constructorArguments, IInterceptor[] interceptors)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy(Type classToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options, Object[] constructorArguments, IInterceptor[] interceptors)

Comment: See bottom on updated answer for more details on the "empty constructor" problem.

Comment: Thanks @BatteryBackupUnit. At this point I don't think property injection is an option, we're trying to stay away form it. The way i'm creating the Class Proxy manually through Castle libs is currently working fine. But I wanted to get the job done through Ninject extension wrappers.